# Display Records exist in at least one table

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables (table1.table2 and table3),each table has an employee attendance with employee code

Ex:

```
              Table 1    Table 2    Table 3
Employee Code  1001       1001       no record
Employee Code  no record  1002       no record
Employee Code  1003       no record  1003
```

finally i need to display data below.

```
         Table 1 Table 2  Table 3         
1001     Y       Y        N
1002     N       Y        N
1003     Y       N        Y
```

i.e i need to display employee those are present/absent on respective tables.

Comment: Share the exact table schema and it's sample data for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a full outer join:

```
select emp_code, 
       case when t1.emp_code is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as table_1,
       case when t2.emp_code is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as table_2,
       case when t3.emp_code is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as table_3
from table_1 t1
  full outer join table_2 t2 using (emp_code)
  full outer join table_3 t2 using (emp_code);
```

Note that emp_code in the select list is unqualified. The join based on the `using` keyword will return the non-null value of the join condition removing the need for a `coalesce()` or `case`

You didn't state your database, but the above is standard SQL.

Online example: http://rextester.com/XPVSRZ98817

Comment: @YogeshSharma: "SQL" is a standard for a query language.